# What are my options to go from Milan to Lake Maggiore, Italy?

Tags: italy, transportation

What are my ground transport options traveling from Milan to Lake Maggiore? I will be flying into Milan, but will need to get to Verbania on the lake. Where can I get cost and time estimates?

Comment: No I think it was fine before the edit too. We can provide information about *modes* of transportation -- eg. "xyz bus runs from here to here on such-and-such days according to rome2rio". The edit restricts the scope to only external sources of scheduling/cost information and is a fundamentally different question.

Answer (score 5):

You are starting from Milan Malpensa airport, yes?

I can think of three options, unfortunately I am only allowed to post two links, so you can try Google for the other web sites.

1. Train or bus from the airport to Milano Centrale then train to Verbania - use the planner at http://www.trenord.it/en/
2. Tilo train from the airport to Laveno + ferry from Laveno to Intra (google navigazione laghi to find the ferry timetable).
3. Bus from the airport to Gravellona Toce http://www.comazzibus.com/eng/orario.php?p=107 then a taxi to Verbania.

I hope this gives you some possibilities that you can look at and see what would work best for you.

Comment: Your answer is already good enough, so I don't feel the need to post a different one. If you feel like, you can add to your that it's possible (and probably faster and cheaper) to take the city bus from the airport to Gallarate and from there a train to Verbania.